# Adding an API operation that has a different https address

Tags: azure-api-management

I'm new to APIM and I have created an APIM instance and an API (called Ratings). I have pointed to an Azure function that has a couple of endpoints that work fine.

I need to add two other operations that point to another endpoint like https:///api/GetUser/?userid={_userid}.

I'm a bit confused as to how to take my https://larrys.azure-api.net//??????? and then add the call the the https address.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks|

L

Answer (score 0):

You can use [set-backend-service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies#SetBackendService) policy at the operation level and override the API level behavior.

Example: `<set-backend-service base-url="base URL of the backend service" />`